# Can a device accidentally transmit a Teardrop attack?

Tags: firewalls, logging, tcp

On reviewing the firewall log on my router (supplied by my fibre provider), I noticed a few curious entries. Several teardrop or derivative attacks, I'd expect to see things like this in the log from public addresses, but these appear to originate from within the network.

[image]

I understand what a teardrop attack is - using the fragment offset field to confuse a device during reassembly of tcp packets, thus causing denial of service in vulnerable devices. In this case the firewall appears to have blocked it.

I have a reasonable confidence that none of the devices within my network are compromised, I believe the device that was assigned this IP at the time was actually an android based phone. So, can a device accidentally generate a tcp packet that the firewall could interpret as a teardrop, or this more likely to be a spoofed Ip in the source address?

Comment: A count of '1' something is not an attack. Worry if you have hundreds of thousands.

Comment: I'm well aware of that and i never said there was only one.

Answer (score 2):

This is inconclusive.

Because port 3702 is assigned to [WS-Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery) :

> Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery) is a technical
>   specification that defines a multicast discovery protocol to locate
>   services on a local network. It operates over TCP and UDP port 3702
>   and uses IP multicast address 239.255.255.250. As the name suggests,
>   the actual communication between nodes is done using web services
>   standards, notably SOAP-over-UDP.

So it can be anything in the Android(tablet, phone,etc) that make use of WD-Discovery. If you think none of the Android application should talk to any local web services, then you should carry out further investigation, e.g. turn off all application and turn on one by anytime to observe network behavior.

Comment: How can Android apps use ws-discovery?  **Is it the same as Network service discovery (NSD)**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Android doesn't lock out application from using other local network discovery protocol. Nevertheless, as I mentioned, the risk is not conclusive.